# How to get SharePoint 2013 to install on Server 2012R2 DataCenter?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sharepoint-2013

I'm hung up on a "Error: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role." error (as shown in the install log).

So far, I've run across a couple supposed fixes (they don't work for me).  Microsoft's site lists a KB that needs to be installed (and also some PowerShell to run).  Other sites have a policy modification to get updates from MS directly (bypassing WSUS).  Unfortunately, none of these seem to make any difference.  What else should I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. Oh man. Server 2012 R2 is not on the compatibility list for Sharepoint 2013.

Sp1 for Sharpeoint 2013, coming "early 2014" is supposed to fix that.

Same with Exchange 2013.

YOu should NOT install server software without reading documentation.

CHecK:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2891274

Let me quote:
"Currently, Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 is not supported for installation on computers running the Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system."

Simple like that.

Comment: Good to know.  I read the docs (whole mountains of them for SharePoint 2013), but apparently missed that somewhere.  Hard to believe, since Microsoft is normally so good about compatibility.  I guess I'll have to put this project on hold for now.

Comment: Well, Microsoft is actually kinda picky regarding compatibility on the server-side. The good part is if you follow the documentation exactly as it is written, you won't have any problems. The bad part is if there is no documented compatibility then you will have problems :-)

Comment: Not long. Basically the compatibility for Sharepoint 2013 des not list Server 2012 R2. Msdoes not keep the server back.... SP1 is scheduled hopefully soon... Exchange + Sharepoint are the "victims" for the moment. We all wait and hope ;) Also about the new goodies. Rumour has for a April release (There is a conference with a related topic).

Comment: Before the release of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1 (SP1), Microsoft did not support the installation of SharePoint Server 2013 in a Windows Server 2012 R2-based environment. However, with the release of SharePoint Server 2013 SP1, this configuration is supported in Windows Server 2012 R2. You can now download SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 from the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN), the Volume Licensing Service Center (VLSC), and the Microsoft Partner Network (MPN).